# C# Adding Events!

Tags: c#, events, combobox

how can I add a double click event to a control that doesn't have a double click event =P

like a combo box!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<sarcasm>`Use more exclamation points - that usually gets the job done!`</sarcasm>`

But, seriously, you can't. Try checking for the simple "Click" event and then see if the time between two successive clicks is small enough. I'm not sure where you can find the system double-click timing though. Try googling for that.

However, I would seriously think twice about adding such non-standard behavior to a standard control. Users normally don't expect this so they will quite likely be unhappy about this. Remember - the best UI is the one that offers the user least surprises. Better think of another way to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Actually a System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox has a DoubleClick event, it's just hidden from your editor:

```
    // Summary:
    //     This event is not relevant for this class.
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public event EventHandler DoubleClick;
```

I'm guessing they chose to hide the event because it won't ever be called :)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is [you don't](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/36f03ba0-f7d9-4f94-9565-1453e24cf4ee).

The long answer is you subscribe to the Click event and see if another click event was called in the last XXX milliseconds, [as in this post](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-csharp/17131/double-click-on-combobox).

Answer (score 3):

you don't double click it, you make it look like you double-clicked it, if you are evil enough.

```
private void box_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
      {
         TimeSpan Current = DateTime.Now - LastClick;
         TimeSpan DblClickSpan =
         TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime);

         if (Current.TotalMilliseconds <= DblClickSpan.TotalMilliseconds)
         {
     // Code to handle double click goes here
         }

         LastClick = DateTime.Now;
      }
}
```

[double click on combobox](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-csharp/17131/double-click-on-combobox)

Comment: Double click by default selects the whole text in ComboBox. If you want to handle double click yourself the `combo_MouseDoubleClick` should work, but it won't. I do not understand why we have to tweek this behavior to get working. Timespan between two Datetimes? OMG.. Maybe we could go to connect.microsoft.com and suggest DoubleClick to fully work in Combos.

Comment: @JuniorMayhé not sure about if Microsoft would care about our idea but why not try :)

Comment: Sure, besides connect.microsoft.com, there is a site where we can search, add and vote for features in many topics: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

Comment: Depending on what is implemented for the double click this might not be 100% correct. When the double click is handled need to set LastClick to something in the past (e.g. DateTime.MinValue). Otherwise 3 clicks may be registered as 2 double clicks

Answer (score 0):

According to my copy of Reflector, System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox, from assembly System.Windows.Forms, Version 2.0.0.0, DOES have a DoubleClick event.

Comment: Yup, and the MSDN agrees.  However, the documentation for the event says "This event supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.  This event is not relevant for this class." (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.doubleclick.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The TextBox control inside the combobox steals/consumes the DoubleClick event, so you have to use the Click event on the ComboBox to listen for both clicks?

[Source](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/36_2004_4_0_0_212311/double-click-on-combobox.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a way (given that the text box eats the event); I also saw a note that double click is not relevant for this control.  I also did not find a way to capture the event from the inner text control

You may want to rethink why you want to change the behavior from the default (namely, selecting the current text).  If you change expected behavior too much, your application becomes that much harder to use.